# Is it Master of Science in Engineering (MSE) or MEng given the Swedish "civilingenjör"?

Tags: masters, engineering, titles

The Swedish "civilingenjör" is translated to "master of science in engineering"; in my case, it's "master of science in computer science and engineering." There isn't a plain "MEng" but the civilingenjör is both M.Sc. and M.Eng., distinct from the "master curriculum," which does not have the word engineering in the title. Do you agree that I can say without exaggeration that I completed a master of engineering when granted the "Master of Science in Computer Science and Engineering" Swedish "civilingenjör datateknik"?

Answer (score 1):

When moving between different educational systems, titles can be difficult to translate. Some jurisdictions have a process for recognizing foreign titles (Germany), but even  then, depending on the use you make of the title, there are variant degrees of strictness. Others just use an expert agency (US) to validate foreign titles used as qualifications for educational purposes. But see the case of an engineer who was not allowed to call himself an "engineer" and use Mathematics until a court intervened ([https://ij.org/press-release/oregon-engineer-wins-traffic-light-timing-lawsuit/#:~:text=Mats%20sued%20the%20board%20in,permanent%20injunction%20securing%20Mats%27s%20rights](https://ij.org/press-release/oregon-engineer-wins-traffic-light-timing-lawsuit/#:%7E:text=Mats%20sued%20the%20board%20in,permanent%20injunction%20securing%20Mats%27s%20rights))

If you are looking for work, usually the "nearest equivalent" is good enough. You question would fall under this. Just make sure that you give the original title and the granting academic institution in such things as CVs. In social life, the same applies. Just don't give a wrong impression like making a three years degree into a five year degree.

If you are looking for licensing, you need to follow whatever the licensing agency needs and decides.

If the title is protected, things can be iffy, but even German courts can be amazingly pragmatical if there is no deceit involved. (In Germany, you need to have permission to use certain academic titles like Professor or Doktor).

Answer (score 1):

The civilingenjör title does not have a direct equivalent in most educational systems. If possible at your institution, try to get separate diplomas issued for the bachelor's and master's degrees making up the civilingenjör degree (on top of the civilingenjör diploma). Assuming the master's courses you take are organized in a program, a degree from that program is likely to say "master of science" or "master of engineering", which is much easier to communicate internationally. Even if your institution does not want to award you that degree separately, you could try to figure out what's listed on degrees awarded to students who are part of the master's program but not the civilingenjör program, or just take a guess. Close enough is good enough for most purposes, of course. But if you can be officially awarded an M.Sc./M.Eng. you can avoid some raised eyebrows internationally and ensure you're being accurate.

Note: This assumes a five-year (post-Bologna process) civilingenjör program.